# Is there a way to run IOS Simulator on Windows 10?

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

I want to run IOS Simulator on Windows 10.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think its possible to get the iOS simulator working on Windows. But if you are willing to explore a dual boot setup, have patience (and a supported motherboard/processor), then you could use [OpenCore](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Install-Guide/) or [Clover](https://github.com/CloverHackyColor/CloverBootloader/releases) to get a macOS running on your pc. This will give you access to the iOS simulator and the other xcode tools.

If you take this route then you should know that macOS doesnt support ntfs writes out the box. This means that if you decide to create a shared volume that both the mac and windows partition would read and write from, then you would either need a 3rd party ntfs drive (e.g. [macfuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/)) or to format your volume to exFAT (this gave me the best results and was free)

If you intend to run the latest macOS I would recommend going with OpenCore. The latest Clover versions ports pieces of OpenCore to it, and finding documentation on configuring the new Clover was a hassle for me. If you are fine with running Catalina and using an older xcode (and thus older iOS simulator), then I would recommend giving [tonymac tools](https://www.tonymacx86.com/resources/categories/tonymacx86-downloads.3/) a shot. Building the installer took with very little effort. You need an account to download the tools (this is free but they ask for motherboard/gpu model for community posts and verification that you can actually run their software)

Answer (score 1):

Native testing of iOS apps is only possible on an Apple device. But there are some ways to overcome that.

Some reference to external iOS simulating platforms: https://fossbytes.com/best-ios-emulators-pc-windows-mac/